# Product of infinite series from -infinity to infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to multiply 2 series which sums over all integers? $$ \Bigr( \sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty a_i x ^i\Bigr)\Bigr(\sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty b_j x ^j\Bigr)$$

Comment: You could break each sum into two sums, then distribute.

Comment: @SantanaAfton That doesn't really simplify the question, since $\left(\sum_{i=-\infty}^{-1} a_ix^i\right)\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} b_jx^j$ still has infinite sums.

Comment: If the series converge absolutely, you can write the product as $$\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} \Biggl(\sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty} a_k b_{n-k}\Biggr)x^n.$$